# XSL Selecting A Nested Field (From Shopify XML Output)

Tags: xml, xslt, shopify, nested, xml-formatting

I'm formatting a Shopify output XML file and need to select the first-name field, however they have multiple, nested, first-name fields.  How do I go about selecting one?

```
<order>
    <billing-address type="Address">
        <first-name>Bob</first-name>
        <last-name>Biller</last-name>
    </billing-address>
    <shipping-address type="Address">
        <first-name>Steve</first-name><!-- Trying to select shipping-address >> first-name -->
        <last-name>Shipper</last-name>
    </shipping-address>
</order>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure about the template you are using for this, but as example if you have a template matching the whole order:

```
<xsl:template match="order">  
  First name: <xsl:value-of select="shipping-address/first-name"/>
  Last name: <xsl:value-of select="shipping-address/last-name"/>
</xsl:template>
```

has the result

```
First name: Steve
Last name: Shipper
```

Answer (score 0):

You know Shopify is scrapping the output of XML for all API work and webhooks?

Comment: Where did you hear that?  I can't find anything on the matter and if that's the case will they be keeping JSON?

Comment: Right on the API homepage... it says this... 

Shopify's API currently supports both JSON and XML, however JSON is the preferred method for API consumption. Over the coming months, XML will slowly be deprecated. All concerned parties will receive a deprecation notice once this comes to pass.